# Laravel Cartalyst Platform displays problems with /bootstrap/cache/config.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, cartalyst-sentinel

Developing with Laravel Cartalyst Platform Im facing problems with /bootstrap/cache/config.php

If I run `php artisan config:cache` the following problem appears:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()
```

If I delete /bootstrap/cache/config.php the application runs ok, but as soon I run php artisan config:cache

```
=> php artisan config:cache 
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
```

and a new config.php is created inside bootstrap/cache, but as soon the file is created the app crash again and white page appears.

Debugging php_error.log displays the following information:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not
> exist in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:719
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(719):
>
> ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
>
> ## 1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(598):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
>
> ## 2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(567):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config')
>
> ## 3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config')
>
> ## 4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(107):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
>
> ## 5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>
> on line 719

I cannot find which config file is missing or what can I do in order to solve the error.

brgds.

Comment: Try composer install and after that composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: @VaheGalstyan same error for composer install, nothing with composer dump

Comment: @VaheGalstyan error -> > php artisan platform:check-env-file

                                                           
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()          
                                                           

Script php artisan platform:check-env-file handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/6b60dc66502811ea6fa732ac2f242419516972cf, try this one. And check your env file please.

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I included that info but no success. As soon bootstrap/cache/config.php is created the application crashes.

Comment: try remove vendor and reinstall composer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144122/discussion-between-vahe-galstyan-and-s-h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a platform problem. Cartalyst already solved the situation with an upgrade in github repository.